# Looping FCM token in CURL script from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a curl script that connects to Firebase in order to send push notificaitions but the problem is that the notification is sent to only one registration token, when it is supposed to send to multiple registration tokens (devices)

below is the CURL code

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$body=$_POST['message'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$url=$_POST['url'];


$path_to_fcm='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs";

$sql="SELECT * FROM fcm_info";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$key=$row[1];   

}

$headers=array(

'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
'Content-Type:application/json'

);

$message = array( 
'title'     => $title,
'body'      => $body,
'webUrl'    => $url,
'vibrate'   => 1,
'sound'      => 1
 );

 $fields = array( 

'to'               =>$key,
'data'  => $message,
'priority'=>'high'
 );

 $payload=json_encode($fields);

 $curl_session=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

 $result=curl_exec($curl_session);

 mysqli_close($con);

  ?>
```

Comment: You have to wrap a loop around your curl code populating a new token on each iteration.

Comment: I did, try to wrap around the curl code, (i put the closing curly brace after $result), but it sent the notification to the second FCM TOKEN

Comment: please update your code

Comment: How many users is this going out too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I noticed was you were storing your curl result into the variable `$result`.  That is the same variable that your query results are in, thus replacing it's value.  That will cause problems.

Give this a try.

```
require 'init.php';
$body = $_POST['message'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$url = $_POST['url'];


$path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs";

$sql="SELECT * FROM fcm_info";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


$headers = array(

'Authorization:key=' . $server_key,
'Content-Type:application/json'

);

$message = array( 

  'title'     => $title,
  'body'      => $body,
  'webUrl'    => $url,
  'vibrate'   => 1,
  'sound'      => 1

 );

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

 $fields = array( 

'to'        => $row[1],
'data'      => $message,
'priority'  =>'high'

 );

 $payload = json_encode($fields);

 $curl_session = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
 curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

 $curlResults[] = curl_exec($curl_session); //Changed the name of variable so it 
 //did not overwrite your query results.

 mysqli_close($con);

}
```